# Como fazer variação inter-semanal no R

Tags: r

Tenho uma base de dados no formato longo e necessito fazer a variação inter-semanal, ou seja, o dado de hoje / dado 7 dias atrás - 1.

Código que utilizei, mas está fazendo a variação do dia anterior:

```
library(readr)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                                        ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

dados[["variacaoCasos"]] <- ((dados$casosAcumulados/lag(dados$casosAcumulados, k = 7))-1)
```

Base de dados que estou utilizando: https://covid.saude.gov.br/

Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar as funções `dplyr::lag()` e `base::diff()`.

A função `diff(x, n)` vai retornar a diferença dos valores de `n` dias atras.

A função `lag(x, n)` vai retornar os valores de `n` dias atras.

Assim, com o código abaixo temos uma taxa de crescimento semanal.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dados <- read_delim("~/Downloads/arquivo_geral.csv", 
                    ";", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)

dados %>% 
  group_by(regiao, estado) %>% 
  mutate(dif_semanal = c(rep(NA, 7), diff(casosAcumulados, 7)),
         percentual_dif = dif_semanal / lag(casosAcumulados, 7)) %>% 
  select(-ends_with("os")) %>% 
  tail()
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#> # Groups:   regiao, estado [1]
#>   regiao       estado data       dif_semanal percentual_dif
#>   <chr>        <chr>  <date>           <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-18         183          0.316
#> 2 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-19         213          0.347
#> 3 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-20         234          0.367
#> 4 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-21         230          0.353
#> 5 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-22         264          0.387
#> 6 Centro-Oeste DF     2020-04-23         247          0.345
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Obrigado pela solução! Funcionou perfeitamente.